# What diameter threaded rod to brace crotch of tree with two 12" codominant stems

Tags: tree

Red maple tree has two codominant stems, each of them 12" in diameter. Would a 1" diameter rod suffice to brace the stems 12" above the crotch?

[image: cable and brace]
[image: bracing diagram]
[image: codominant maple]

Comment: This sounds like a job for an arborist, not a good area for a WAG unless the tree is in the middle of a field with no houses, people or animals near.

Comment: If both sides have similar canopies a solid stick of “all thread” may work but if they are different or one side gets cut back more or is smaller the solid rod may end up being a problem. I have used rod and cable on willow’ and oak’s the size of the hole was not much of a problem in either case but making sure to seal the outer layer will protect the tree.

Comment: I would imagine 1" to be excessive.  Larger holes present a greater risk to the tree.  They recommend a height of 2/3 the tree's height above the crotch, which gives the tie a lot of leverage.

Comment: Why the downvote? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: @K H: 2/3 the tree's height above the crotch is for the cable location, not the bracing rod. They're separate (but complementary) things that can be done.

Comment: Downvote reversed, no reason provided, site suggests a comment should be left so so the person can learn, I don’t see anything wrong with the question and it includes a photo of the tree in question I think that helps to make it a good question.

Comment: If I had to guess at the downvote it's because either 1) this isn't strictly a home improvement question, or 2) the question requires both a high degree of expertise and more conditional information than has been provided. It's hard to make a good judgement about the integrity of a tree from one window into its structure.

Answer (score 1):

A 1" grade A rod has a breaking tensile strength of 60,000 PSI<sup>[source](https://www.fastenal.com/product/fasteners/rods-and-studs/threaded-rods/600173;jsessionid=+7gMeeV+BCyIQQoFkZNJwsfs.443d7b2e-1555-3602-a586-c0d73327934b?categoryId=600173&level=3&isExpanded=true&productFamilyId=23394)</sup>. If the cross-sectional area of such a rod is 0.785", it'll carry ~47,100 lbs.

So, is your tree heavier than 47,100 lbs? There you go and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: It has to deal with wind forces as well, not just the dead weight of the wood.

Comment: @mr blint how much do you think your tree weighs? I work in a lumber mill and a unit of wet lumber is 3-5k depending on the length and board size, look at the next semi truck loaded with lumber, maxed out at ~80k load. A single unit of 12’ would be more wood than 2ea 12” round pieces 48’ long. Or less than 5k for the 2 branches combined. You are only preventing them from splitting the tree itself is supporting them now so if you add ~50k in additional strength that is probably more than the root system could take n a storm, I think this answer is deserving of at least an up vote.